# My address picker for Rails (address_picker-rails) works with the first input, but not the second?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, geolocation

I'm using the address_picker-rails gem and it works perfectly for the first input, but for some reason not the second. I went through it a million times now. Any thoughts?

The _new form code below with the Jquery:

```
  <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being      
   saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>
<fieldset>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :from %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :from, :class => 'address-picker-input' %>
</div>
 </fieldset>
<fieldset>
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :to %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :to, :class => 'address-picker-input' %>

</div>
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">

    //AddressPickerRails.Pickers.applyOnReady({
    //    'onLoad':function (railsPicker) {
    //        console.debug("callback for a single post with ID '%s'",   
           railsPicker.getIdPrefix());
    //    }
    //});

    AddressPickerRails.Pickers.apply({
        'onLoad':function (railsPicker) {
            console.debug("callback for a single post with ID '%s'", 
             railsPicker.getIdPrefix());
        }
    });
</script>


 <div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="field">
<label for="post_to">To</label><br>
<input class="address-picker-input ui-autocomplete-input" id="post_to" name="post[to]"   
size="30" type="text" autocomplete="off"><span role="status" aria-live="polite"   
class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">19 results are available, use up and down arrow 
keys to navigate.</span>
</div>


<div class="field">
<label for="post_from">From</label><br>
<input class="address-picker-input" id="from_field" name="post[from]" size="30" 
type="text">
</div>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: could you post the generated HTML code of the form?

Comment: Ok I added it high above properly.

Comment: Nothing works. Really no one has any idea!!!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a map element for each address field:

```
<div id="post_to_map_wrapper" class="address-picker-map-wrapper">
  <div id="post_to_map" class="address-picker-map"></div>
</div>

<div id="post_from_map_wrapper" class="address-picker-map-wrapper">
  <div id="post_from_map" class="address-picker-map"></div>
</div>
```

The new 0.3.0 version fixes this!

Comment: I checked and version 0.3.0 does fix this! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Check the dom and make sure that the two fields have distinct dom ID's. Also, are you seeing any javascript errors or debug output in the console?

**Update:** 
To set the id explicitly (to guarantee uniqueness) instead of letting rails guess:

```
<%= f.text_field :from, :class => 'address-picker-input', :id => 'from_field' %>
```

Comment: No errors in the debug console. No idea how to change the dom?

Comment: when I say dom ID's, I'm just talking about the input id attributes in the HTML source. Just use 'View source', firebug, or whatever else to check the generated HTML. if the inputs have the same id's, that might cause this.

Comment: I thought so and did check it and yes they do have the same ID's. Trying to fix it. It does work for the Gem builder and his demo app with the same IP's so don't think thats the problem => address_picker-rails-demo / app / assets / stylesheets / scaffolds.css.scss => I give up now!

Comment: Hi, if you could be so kind. Its def the ID's, but they are not in the scaffold_css - is there a secret place where they hide ;)?